# Access value of maven_jar.artifact from Skylark rule

Tags: java, maven, bazel

In my Skylark rule, I am looking through all my deps - some of them are maven_jar instances defined in my WORKSPACE file.  For those, I would like to access the value of `maven_jar.artifact`, but as far as I can tell it isn't available. Is it possible to get at that value?

For example, if my WORKSPACE has:

```
maven_jar(
  name = "com_google_guava_guava",
  artifact = "com.google.guava:guava:20.0",
)
```

And my BUILD file has something like this:

```
my_rule(
    name = "foo",
    deps = ["@com_google_guava_guava//jar"]         
)
```

In the implementation of `my_rule`, I would like to get the value `com.google.guava:guava:20.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to file a feature request for this:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new

The instance of the `maven_jar` rule in the workspace file isn't available to the rules in BUILD files, only the rules which the workspace rule generates are (i.e., `@com_google_guava_guava//jar`). Off the top of my head, `maven_jar` would have to generate a rule into the jar's workspace which has an attribute with the value of `artifact`, and that rule would need to create a provider containing that value for other rules to consume.

(There does happen to be `META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml` inside the jar, which seems to have the information you want, but I don't know if you can rely on that for all jars from maven, but either way, the contents of the jar aren't available at analysis time (within the rule implementation))